# Psycopg2 sql query parameterization, how to pass the contents of two variables to the request body?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Need to pass 2 variables to sql query body
The official documentation says that parameters are passed through a variable as follows, but this only works with one parameter:

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO authors (name) VALUES (%s);" # Note: no quotes
data = ("O'Reilly", )
cur.execute(SQL, data)
```

how it would be possible to pass two variables, that is, something like this:

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO authors (%s) VALUES (%s);" 
data_1 = ("name",)
data_2 = ("O'Reilly", )
cur.execute(SQL, data_1,data_2)
```

Comment: Parameters only work with data values e.g. the part in `VALUES`. The column name you are trying to pass in is an  identifier. From the docs: "Only query values should be bound via this method: it shouldn’t be used to merge table or field names to the query (Psycopg will try quoting the table name as a string value, generating invalid SQL)."  Take a look at this module in `psycopg2` [Sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is my mistake that I showed not an accurate example of the problem I am facing, my script looks more like this:
SQL = “”” select *from table1 where dt in (%s)
union all
select * from table2 where dt in(%s)”””
So I need to pass same value to the different places

Comment: Modify your question to show the correct query. You have two choices: 1) Repeat the value in the sequence you are passing to the query string 2) Use named arguments e.g. `%(name)s`. Use will need to use a dict instead of sequence to pass in the values, but you only have to include the `"name": "O'Reilly"` item once. The value will be substituted wherever there is a `%(name)s`

Comment: "Use will..." in above should be "You will ..." .